# Uniqueness in exponential map on Lie groups

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lie-groups

I am working through the book *Stratified Groups and their Sub-Laplacians* by Bonfiglioli, Lanconelli, and Uguzonni.

Let $X=\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j(x)\partial_j$ be a smooth vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and identify $X$ with $(XI)(x)=\begin{pmatrix}a_1(x)\\ \vdots \\a_n(x)\end{pmatrix}$. By the Picard-Lindelof theorem, for each $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, there exists $\varepsilon>0$ and a unique $\gamma_x:[-\varepsilon,\varepsilon]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $(XI)(\gamma_x(t))=\gamma_x'(t)$ for all $t\in (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ and $\gamma_x(0)=x$. The curve $\gamma_x$ is called an integral curve of $X$ . Now let $(\mathbb{G},\circ)$ be a Lie group on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathfrak{g}$ its Lie algebra of left invariant vector fields. Let $X\in \mathfrak{g}$. You can extend $\gamma_x$ to an integral curve $\Gamma_x$ to $X$ on $[0,2\varepsilon]$ by $\Gamma_x(t)=\gamma_x(\varepsilon)\circ x^{-1}\circ \gamma_x(t-\varepsilon)$ for $t\in [\varepsilon,2\varepsilon]$ and $\Gamma_x(t)=\gamma_x(t)$ for $t\in [0,\varepsilon]$. Similarly for $t\in [-2\varepsilon,-\varepsilon]$. Repeating this procedure you can get an integral curve $\Gamma_x(t)$ to $X$ defined for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$. My question is whether $\Gamma_x$ is unique in any way, since the book then goes on to say that the map $(x,t)\mapsto \exp(tX)(x):=\Gamma_x(t)$ is well defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and I feel like the extended $\Gamma_x$ would have to be unique in order for this to be true. How would one go about justifying uniqueness?

Comment: Yes, $\Gamma_x$ is unique: each small parts of it is locally unique by the cited theorem.